# Sending PHP json_encode array to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

ok, i guess I need help ! I searched with every keyword I could think off, but I still cant figure out, please help. Am more of a php guy, and I've just started with jQuery.

Basically, what I am trying to do is to send a jQuery post from a click function. And based on whatever is returned by my php function, show/hide 2 divs. My php function returns a "json_encode" array with 2 simple values, like such :

//==================PHP code ==================================

```
$message_for_user = "blah blah";
$calculatedValue = 1230;
$responseVar = array(
                    'message'=>$message_for_user,
                    'calculatedValue'=>$calculatedValue
                    );
echo (json_encode($responseVar));
```

//==================PHP code End ==================================

My javascript code is supposed to accept the values returned by php :

//==================Javascript code ==================================

```
$("div.calculator_result").click(function()
{
    $.post('myCalculator.php' ,{qid:itemID},function(response)
    {
        $("div.calculation_value").show(500).html(response['calculatedValue']);
        $("div#message_for_user").show(500).html(response['message']);
    }
}
```

//==================Javascript code End ==================================

Unfortunately, on the javascript side of my project, the divs are not updated with the values returned by my php functions .... where am I wrong? I hope I was clear in my question, if not, do let me know, and I shall provide any extra info required.

Another thing is that earlier, I was echo'ing only a single value, that is the calculated value (echo $calculatedValue), and everything worked fine, its only after I shifted to echo'in the json encode array that things dont work

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var json = $.parseJSON(response); alert(json.message);
```

Comment: Based on your answer, this is what I tried : var resp_object = $.parseJSON(response); $("div.calculation_value").html(resp_object.calculatedValue);       Unfortunately, that dint work for me, mate. I'm on php ver 5.2.14, if that helps

Comment: alrite, that works. For some twisted reason, I had a version of jquery which was older than 1.4.1, and it seems jQuery.parseJSON was added only in 1.4.1

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `dataType` option:

```
$.post('myCalculator.php' ,{qid:itemID},function(response)
{
    $("div.calculation_value").show(500).html(response['calculatedValue']);
    $("div#message_for_user").show(500).html(response['message']);
}, 'json');
```

NB I have also added the closing brackets `)` where you have missed them.

Answer (score 1):

You must parse the JSON response. jQuery has this built-in functionality (thankfully, because otherwise IE6 and 7 don't natively support JSON). Set a variable equal to this:

```
$.parseJSON(response)
```

And then, if you're not familiar with JSON format, check the response headers (using Firebug or similar,) and that will help you pick which keys' values you want. If you're looping, I would look into [for in statements](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp) once the response has been parsed.

EDIT: Using [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), the parsing is done automatically. Write less, do more. :)

Answer (score 0):

All you gotta do, its tell the Ajax call that you're receiving data type "json". In other words...

```
$.ajax({
   url: "external_file",
   method:"post",
   dataType: "json",  // **************** Note dataType****************
   success:function(response){
       console.log(response)
       // Response will be a javascript array, instead of a string.
   },
   error: function(){
       alert('something went wrong.')
   }
})
```