# Accessing json from an ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending PHP json_encode array to jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240763/sending-php-json-encode-array-to-jquery)

I have a little function that searches a database for a name through $.post, and it returns details of users with matching search details.
The json is produced in php and looks like so:

> Array (
>   [0] => Array ( [user] => 17 [fn] => blah [ln] => gnaaa [email] => hello@gmail.com )
>   [1] => Array ( [user] => 18 [fn] => blee [ln] => gnaaa [email] => apple@fdf.com )
>   [2] => Array ( [user] => 19 [fn] => orange [ln] => gnaaa [email] => banana@gnsd.com ) )

Now the javascript pulls the user input data from the html, and posts it to the php script

```
function searchuser() {  
    var searchvar = $('#searchbar').html();
    $.post("Scripts/search.php", {name: searchvar}, function(data) {
        alert("userid: " + data[0][user]);
    });
}
```

So here I am trying to alert the number 17, but nothing seems to be working.
I'm guessing I've got something wrong with the syntax, but I can't figure out what the right way is. I am also using jQuery, so I'm guessing there's a neater way to do this but I wanted to try plain javascript first.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are other ways as well though: - Set the right content response headers in your PHP script. - Pass `'json'` as fourth parameter to `$.post`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have 'data' parsed as a JSON object, you will need to add `dataType: "json"` or "jsonp" to your post call.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: This and I needed single marks around user so ['user'] Thanks!