# Check if cookie exists in jquery not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, cookies

So I've been searching a lot how to do it but nothing seems to work for me. I have the main file 'page.html' and 'signin.php' which shows a communicate after successful login and a button for returning to 'page.html'. When I come back to 'page.html' after login I want 'register' and 'login' tabs to disappear and 'logout' tab to show up. But after I come back to 'page.html' nothing happens.

I'm using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie jquery plugin to check if cookie exists.

PHP CODE in 'signin.php'

```
 if(!isset($error)){
 $result=$connect->query("SELECT * From users WHERE
    dblogin='$login' AND dbpassword='$password'");

    if ($result->num_rows >= 1){
        echo '<div class="sign-up-success" id="sign-up-success">You have just logged in!</div>';
        $userVar = array(
            'login' => $login,
            'password' => $password,
        );
            setcookie("logincookie", json_encode($userVar));
        echo '<a href="page.html" class="home-page">Go back to home page</a>';
    }
};
```

JQUERY

```
$(function (user) {
"use strict";
var json = $.parseJSON(user);
alert(json.message);
if ($.cookie('logincookie')) {
    $('#register').hide();
    $('#login').hide();
    $('#logout').show();
}
});
```

Comment: Have you tested it after removing all of your authentication logic?

Comment: uhm. `$.parseJSON(user);` wut, `user === $`

Comment: yeah, I tested it

Comment: You didn't read your console for errors. Line 3 causes one. Your problem is unrelated to cookies.

Comment: My console doesn't show any errors unfortunately, so what should I do?

Comment: Make sure the code you've provided to us matches the code you are using. The code you've provided should throw an error and not cause an alert.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery code is the same. I'm using Brackets to write it so maybe it just doesn't see the error.

Comment: well...you don't have a syntax error, it's a logic error. your editor isn't going to catch it.

Comment: ohh, that makes sense. While writing this code I was looking at this post, that's why my third line looks like it does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240763/sending-php-json-encode-array-to-jquery and I think I didn't mistype anything. So I'm just wondering why it works there but not here.

Comment: because... `user` isn't an ajax response string, it's `jQuery`. The first parameter passed to the callback of `$(callback)` is always `$`

Comment: okay, so what should I pass to the callback to make it work?

Comment: i have no idea what you are trying to do with `user`. so... i don't know. that part of your code doesn't make sense to me. Maybe just remove it? it looks useless.

Comment: okay, so I deleted 'var json = $.parseJSON(user);
alert(json.message);' and it still doesn't work, divs don't hide and don't show up, php recognizes the cookie and reacts when it exists, but jquery does not

Comment: okay, I made it work finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by myself. It required to delete

```
var json = $.parseJSON(user);
alert(json.message);
```

and... link jquery plugin to html, I don't know why it got deleted.